# Image links wont work in any browser

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

Im pretty new to html/css so maybe this is a really simple thing but none of my images links on one page of the site show up when I try to click on them the image shows but the link never appears and the cursor never changes anyway here is the relevant section of code

```
<div id="content">
<div id="imagelink">
    <a href="#"><img border="0" src="Images/pic.png" alt="A Picture"  /></a>
</div>
```

```
#imagelink {
background-image:url("Images/file.png");
display:block;
height:224px;
width:401px;
text-indent:-9999px;
position:absolute;
left:15%;
top:25%;
```

}

Comment: Can you give us an example URL? I am not entirely sure why you'd be using CSS like this for #imagelink unless it relates to some other CSS. With a -9999 text-indent your image link is probably being pushed off the screen to the left...

Comment: Was only using that when trying out a css version i found on some site but it didnt work once i deleted the text-indent it still didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use the img tag and instead, use a div for your image:

```
<a href="#" target="_BLANK">
<div class="myImage"></div>
</a>

.myImage{
    background: url(Images/file.png) no-repeat top center;
    height: 224px;
    width: 401px;
}
```

Comment: yea nothing changed same problem

Comment: What's the content of the div named "content" ?  I also notice that the "content" div is not closed.

Comment: The content div holds all the website content apart from the header and footer

Comment: @Ben B after playing around with it a bit more I discovered that the content div was the problem. When the link was inside it, It wont work but once its outside it works fine 

Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="imagelink">
    <a href="#"><img border="0" src="Images/pic.png" alt="A Picture"  /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: And in case you didn't catch it... you're missing a `</a>` to end your `<a>` tag.

Comment: would that not just change the link location to that of the image

Answer (score 0):

1. if your server is case sensitive change Images to images
2. add ./ or http://domain.com/path/to/images/ to the paths